# Access method from android plugin in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

This is pretty basic, but I'm not getting success on implementing it from the official Unity docs and YouTube video tutorials, so I asked.

I want to access methods from already made aar plug-in. Its checked as android plug-in by default. The plug-in has following code:

```
package alarm.company.com.unity;

public class myPlugin {

    public String myTest(int i){
        return "Hello your string number is: "+i;
    }

}
```

the compiled aar plug-in is copied into the Unity folder.
Here's the c# code to access that method:

```
const string PluginName = "alarm.company.com.unity.myPlugin";
static AndroidJavaClass _pluginClass;
static AndroidJavaClass _pluginInstance;

public Text text;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

    AndroidJavaClass plugin = new AndroidJavaClass(PluginName);
    string s = plugin.CallStatic<string>("myTest", 9);
    print(s);
    text.text = s;

}
```

`text` is assigned and this script is put on the main camera. But I'm not getting any text back or the text object is not changed, while running in emulator. How can this be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity Plugin development is a bit tricky to get setup at first but once you are able to it is pretty powerful.

Couple things.

1) You are using an AndroidJavaClass and trying to call a non static method in java. Your method in your plugin should be static if you are wanting to use that class.

2) Otherwise you will need to use an AndroidJavaObject to construct your class and then you should be able to call your function.

Hope this helps!

Example Using non Static Code:

Unity Code

```
   using (AndroidJavaObject leetPlugin = new AndroidJavaObject("alarm.company.com.unity.myPlugin")){
        string s = leetPlugin.Call("myTest", 9);
        print(s);
        text.text = s;
    }
```

Android Code

```
public void myTest(int value) {
   return "Your value is " + value;
}
```

Comment: its working with static method, but I cant get any log message on android studio, eg:         Log.i("cool",string);
. Can you say anything about it?

Comment: It has been a while but I am pretty sure you will need to set the Logcat filter to No Filters since your application isnt running from studio. Then you can use the command: 

adb logcat -s Unity ActivityManager PackageManager dalvikvm DEBUG

to filter for all Unity Logs. If you are searching for your specific logs I would recommend using your ClassName instead of "cool". Then you can run the same command above: 

adb logcat -s ClassName

and your logs should show.

Answer (score 0):

Some advises when you work with plugins for unity:

1. Use gradle build system. It generates mainTemplate file in Plugins/Android. You can edit this file and set source java code to your java classes so you don't need to generate aar every time you want to build:

   ```
   sourceSets 
   {
       main
       {
           java
           {
               srcDirs = ['src']
               srcDirs += ['E:/AndroidStudioProjects/PathToJavaClasses']
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. If you want to send something from java code to unity you should extend your activity from unity and call method UnitySendMessage

   ```
   public class MyUnityPlayerActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity{
       public void SendUnityMessage()
       {
            UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(UnityGameObjectName, UNITY_FUNCTION_NAME, 
            params);
       }
   }
   ```